# How the country code of a venue is generated?

Tags: geolocation, geospatial, foursquare

I'm developing an APP using FS API and I need to geolocalize a venue. Nothing particularly difficult, just "US" or "Non-US".
I though of using the country code (CC fields) which come with every venue object, but I'm not sure how this country code is calculated:

a) Is something you infer using the lat and lon of the venue, and therefore something FS calculates directly with Geospatial queries?
b) Is something the user insert manually (not only the CC but the country itself) and therefore is something which can be missing of be mispelled / misinserted?

Cheers,

Alfredo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The country information is built up from a variety of sources, including geolocation and user input. The input is validated though, so there should not be any invalid country codes. You can expect that the country code will be an accurate representation of where the venue is located.